# Confused about Kivy's placement of a "center" of a circle -- screenshot and code included

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to use Kivy just to experiment with a little game. I've been loosely following a tutorial, but I'm basically confused about the way the float layout renders graphics on the screen.

I'm trying to draw the "player" as a rectangle in the middle of the screen. But it clearly isn't rendering in the center (which I've indicated by rendering crosshairs at the center):

[image: Why is there an offset?]

Here's the code:

```
<Game>:
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.size
        Widget:
            id: game
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: dark
                Rectangle:
                    pos: root.center_x/5, 0
                    size: root.width*4/5, root.height
                Color:
                    rgb: violet
                Rectangle:
                    pos: root.center_x, 0
                    size: 2, root.height
                Rectangle:
                    pos: 0, root.center_y
                    size: root.width, 2
        Player:
            id: player
            size_hint: 300, 300
            center_x: root.center_x
            center_y: root.center_y

<Player>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: crimson
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size_hint
        Color:
            rgb: dark
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.x+5, self.y+5
            size: self.size_hint_x-10, self.size_hint_y-10
```

The Python code is really minimal right now; I'm just trying to learn my way around the graphics:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import(Rectangle, Ellipse)
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color

class Player(Widget):
    pass

class Game(Widget):
    player = ObjectProperty(None)

class GameApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

Comment: Any general feedback on how kivy works would be extremely welcome.

Comment: Just noticed that if I set Player's size_hint to 100, 100, it renders exactly in the center. But I'm not sure why that would be...

Comment: `size_hint` is a relative size when compared to other widgets or to the parent (depending on context). It looks like you want to set `size_hint` to `(None, None)` and refer to `self.size` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below.  Use explicit sizes instead of `size_hint` and position them relative to the parent.

```
<Game>:
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.size
        Widget:
            id: game
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 0, 0 
                Rectangle:
                    pos: root.center_x/5, 0
                    size: root.width*4/5, root.height
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 1, 0
                Rectangle:
                    pos: root.center_x, 0
                    size: 2, root.height
                Rectangle:
                    pos: 0, root.center_y
                    size: root.width, 2
        Player:
            id: player
            center_x: root.center_x
            center_y: root.center_y

<Player>:
    size_val_r: 300
    size_val_e: 290
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.8, 0.6, 0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size_val_r, self.size_val_r
            pos: root.width/2 - self.size_val_r/2, self.height/2 - self.size_val_r/2
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 0.6
        Ellipse:
            pos: root.width/2 - self.size_val_e/2, self.height/2 - self.size_val_e/2
            size: self.size_val_e, self.size_val_e
```

Comment: If you want relative sizes, don't use size_hint which will be relative to the parent <player>.  You want to use a multiple of root.width which will be relative to the layout.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this fixed my problem.